# unrar for centos 5.7 needs unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64.rpm which causes an error

Tags: centos, rpm, rar

I'm trying to install unrar package for my cpanel. as some people suggested that I need this package `unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64.rpm`  . So when I run `rpm -ivh unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64.rpm` I get this error:

```
    [root /]# rpm -ivh unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64.rpm
warning: unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 signature: NOKEY, key ID 80420f66
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by unrar-4.20-2.mga3.nonfree.x86_64
[root /]#
```

I saw posts suggesting to install `EPEL` and still the problem exists. I didn't see a relevant for installing the `EPEL` but still I tried and nothing worked.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated.

**Note:** I have `Centos 5.7`

Comment: So you just downvote with no comment. or you just downvote when you have no answer?

Comment: Oh, the reason is this: I answer and you delete my answer with no reason. I suggested that you can't install a Mageia rpm on a CentOS system because of incompatibilities. I suggest rpmforge, as it offers you a solution, namely a comatible unrar rpm and a repository.

Comment: Why are you trying to install a Mageia RPM on a CentOS system?

Comment: @schaiba - Are you sure... I didn't delete any answer. and I would love to hear any answer. I'm in a bit of trouble here so I'm sure I didn't delete any answer. and once again please repost your answer.

Comment: @Renan - because it's the only package for `unrar` that's I've seen sadly..

Comment: @schaiba - I also didn't know that I can delete an answer :D

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: You can't. Somebody else must have. I believe it takes more than one member to delete an answer, so the answer deleted must've ticked off more than one.

Comment: @mamdouhalramadan: See my answer above: install rpmforge from here: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-5aabf02717d5b6b12d47edbc5811404998926a1b . Then 'yum update && yum install unrar'

Comment: @schaiba - thank you.. that should help. please add it as an answer so I can credit it.. and as it appears for rahum comment, I can't be deleted your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install rpmforge from here: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge#head-5aabf02717d5b6b12d47edbc5811404998926a1b . Then 'yum update && yum install unrar'